# Property 'player' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my code :

```
export class Test implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const YTPlayer = require('yt-player');
    const player = new YTPlayer('#player');

    player.load('GKSRyLdjsPA');
    player.setVolume(100);

    player.on('playing', () => {
      console.log(player.getDuration())
    });
  }

  jumpToPoint(time){
    this.player.seek(time);
    this.player.play();
  }

}
```

He is my error :

> Property 'player' does not exist on type

I don't know how to declare the player in `NgOnInit()` and use the player variable in the following code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `const` will make the scope of it the surrounding scope, in this case - the `ngOnInit` function.
You should declare it as a class property:

```
const YTPlayer = require('yt-player');
// import YTPlayer from "yt-player"; - This is the same

export class Test implements OnInit {
  private player: YTPlayer; 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.player = new YTPlayer('#player');
    // Rest of initialization...
  }

  jumpToPoint(time){
    this.player.seek(time); // Should work!
    this.player.play();
  }
}
```

[For further reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#classes)

Comment: How could I add `const YTPlayer = require('yt-player');` in this case ? Because it created a new error : _error TS2304: Cannot find name 'YTPlayer'._

Comment: You should import it in the beginning of the file, is possible. (And also prefer `import` syntax to `require` if possible). I've updated the answer with both options.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import * as YTPlayer from 'yt-player'
export class Test implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }
private player:YTPlayer
  ngOnInit() {
 this.player = new YTPlayer('#player');

    player.load('GKSRyLdjsPA');
    player.setVolume(100);

    player.on('playing', () => {
      console.log(player.getDuration())
    });
  }

  jumpToPoint(time){
    this.player.seek(time);
    this.player.play();
  }

}
```